# UIDAI Adhaar API in PHP

Tags: php, api

```
$curl = curl_init();
$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <Auth uid=”999999990019” tid=”public” ac=”public” sa=”public” ver=”1.6”txn=”AuthDemoClient:public:20160616070338756” lk=”MBFWjkJHNFfLidl8oOHtUwgL5p1ZjDbWrqsMEVEJLVEDpnlNj_CZTg”>
    <Uses pi=”y” pa=”n” pfa=”n” bio=”n” bt=”n” pin=”” otp=”n”/>
    <Tkn type=”” value=””/>
    <Meta udc=”” fdc=”” idc=”” pip=”” lot=”G|P” lov=””/>
    <Skey ci=”” ki=””></Skey>
    <Data type=”X|P”>encrypted PID block</Data>
    <Hmac>SHA-256 Hash of Pid block, encrypted and then encoded</Hmac
    <Signature>Digital signature of AUA</Signature>
  </Auth>
</xml>'; 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://auth.uidai.gov.in/1.6/public/9/9/MH4hSkrev2h_Feu0lBRC8NI-iqzT299_qPSSstOFbNFTwWrie29ThDo");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml','Content-Length:length'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($result);
```

This is the sample code which I wrote.Needs test data for some of the left out attributes like **udc,fdc,idc** etc. When I try to fire this API gets **400-Bad Request**.Help would be appriciated.

Comment: [`Content-Length:length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length)

Comment: Where does the example code come from? Where can the specification for the API be found?

Comment: got the reference from [link](https://uidai.gov.in/images/FrontPageUpdates/aadhaar_authentication_api_1_6.pdf) .